# What is the status of Anatomy Park after Ethan gets "morphized" by Morty

Tags: plot-explanation, rick-and-morty

In Rick and Morty [S1 E3](https://rickandmorty.fandom.com/wiki/Anatomy_Park_(episode)), we explore Rick's Anatomy Park (and Pirates of the Pancreas) he created inside his friend Ruben. After Ruben dies, Rick creates a new Anatomy Park inside of Ethan, Summer's boyfriend.
In a later episode ([S3 E5](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/102938/47313)), after Ethan breaks up with Summer in order to hook up with a different girl, Summer uses Rick's Morphizer to give herself bigger boobs. At the the end of that episode Morty gets revenge by using the Morphizer on Ethan and when we later see him, he is completely misshapen.

My question is, when Morty Morphized Ethan, how did that affect Anatomy Park (and specifically Pirates of the Pancreas)?
Did Rick have to build a new park or did the  whole park get a few "expansions"?

Answer (score 6):

**The Ethan that was morphized is not the Ethan that hosted Anatomy Park.**

[Anatomy Park](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3333828/) occurred in episode 3 of season 1. Later on, at the end of episode 6 ([Rick Potion #9](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3333834/?ref_=ttep_ep6)), we sort of stop tracking this Ethan.

> This is the episode where Rick and Morty accidentally cronenburg their current dimension, and have to take over the lives of a recently-deceased Rick and Morty in another dimension.

As a result, the Ethan that is morphasized is not the Ethan that hosts Anatomy Park. In turn, the two have no bearing on each other.

If the real question is 'what happens to Anatomy Park', we simply don't know. Nothing has been said about the park, itself; we might speculate that it would fall to ruin without the means to continue further maintenance, as was required in the original episode, but all we can really do at this stage is speculate.

---

As an appendum, I suppose it is *possible* that they built an Anatomy Park in the current Ethan. Heck, it's Rick and Morty, so it is entirely possible that the episodes are not sequential in the actual timeline and the morphing *did* occur to the same Ethan. Regardless, they have yet to make any further mention of Anatomy Park, so all we can really do is speculate.

As mentioned In [another answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/102938/47313), we can tell that nothing happened to *Pirates of the Pancreas*, because it doesn't appear to have been rebuilt in the first place.

Comment: How do we know that the new reality *doesn't* have an Anatomy Park?

Comment: @Dr. Sheldon Cooper, how do we know that it does?

Comment: @Dr.SheldonCooper: You are correct. The dimension Rick and Morty migrated to has a lot (if not an almost complete) overlap with their previous dimension, so the Anatomy Park event _could_ have happened too. But we can't know either way, so the question is unanswerable until the question on whether this Ethan hosts an Anatomy Park too get answered by the show, which so far it hasn't.

Answer (score 3):

As an addendum to Gnemlock's answer, ***Pirates of the Pancreas* never was rebuilt**.
When the team reconstructing the theme park calls Rick from within Ethan to sort some things out, Alejandro, the Chief Imaginarian, says to Rick:

> Hey Rick, it’s Alejandro speaking. Um, so we asked ourselves
>   internally, we asked ourselves over here, “Okay, what does a pancreas
>   do?” And the answer was, does it make
>   pirates? No. It makes insulin, you know? So we’re starting with a new—